# clearInterval(); then call interval again

Tags: javascript

I have a setInterval function

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
  if ($('#addNewJuicebox:visible')) {
    clearInterval();
  }
  //rest of function
}, 8000); // refresh every 5000 milliseconds
```

I want to call the setInterval later again, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Call it again the same way you did the first time? I don't understand the question.

Comment: So you want updates to happen if #addNewJuiceBox is visible?

Comment: I want it to stop running if addNewJuicebox is visible, then in another function, I want to call the setInterval to start up again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try breaking your code up into the storage of the interval and the setting.

```
var auto_refresh = "";

function startRefresh() {
  if (auto_refresh != "") {
    // already set
    return;
  }
  auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('#addNewJuicebox:visible')) { 
      clearInterval(auto_refresh); 
      auto_refresh = "";
    }
  }, 8000);
}
```

Added a jsfiddle example for demonstrating starting and stopping an interval

- http://jsfiddle.net/Jf8PT/

Comment: The answer wasn't perfect and I had to modify it quite a bit, but it really did help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @switz hi, how do you solve the problem? I try the above tutorial but doesn't work.. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`clearInterval` takes in a reference to the timer that you want to clear, you need to pass that in to it:

```
var auto_refresh = null;
var refresh = function () {
    if ($('#addNewJuicebox').is(':visible')) {
        clearInterval(auto_refresh);
        auto_refresh = null;
    }
};
var start_refreshing = function() {
    if(auto_refresh != null) return;
    auto_refresh = setInterval(refresh, 8000); 
};
start_refreshing();
```

Comment: The fact that he wants to basically start and stop the task

Comment: Added a response that may make sense of what I said

Comment: @Juan @Switz You can now simply invoke `start_refreshing` whenever you want to restart the timer.

Comment: yeah, that's the approach, I suggested something a bit more reusable

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for

```
Function TaskRunner(run, interval) {
  this._taskId = null;
  this._run = run;
  this._interval = interval
}

TaskRunner.prototype.start = function(){
  if (this._taskId) {
    return; // Already running
  }
  this._taskId = setInterval(this._taskId, this._interval);
}

TaskRunner.prototype.stop = function(){
  if (!this._taskId) {
    return; // Not running
  }
  clearInterval(this._taskId);
  this._taskId = null;
}


var task = new TaskRunner(
  function(){
    if ($('#addNewJuicebox:visible')) {
      task.stop();
    }
   // Do the update     
  }, 5000);

Now you can call `task.start()` from anywhere in your code to restart it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to use setTimeout() instead, so that you have the control you're looking for?